# Wolfram: Transpose Map of an association

Tags: dataset, associations, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to Transpose each value list of association. This is actually a dataset problem, but I thought it would be easier to get answers here for associations.

I currently have a list of associations which looks like this:

```
    assoc = 
{<|"a" -> 5, "b" -> 7, "c" -> 9, "d" -> 8|>,
 <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 12, "c" -> 14, "d" -> 17|>,
 <|"a" -> 8, "b" -> 0, "c" -> 5, "d" -> 32|>}
```

And I want to Transpose each "b","c","d" with each "a": so my output would be:

```
{{"a" -> 5, "b" -> 7},
{"a" -> 5, "c" -> 9},
{"a" -> 5, "d" -> 8},
{"a" -> 3, "b" -> 12}, 
{"a" -> 3, "c" -> 1},
{"a" -> 3, "d" -> 17},
{"a" -> 8, "b" -> 0}, 
{"a" -> 8, "c" -> 5},
{"a" -> 8, "d" -> 32}}
```

I've tried various methods of mapping and transposing, but I can't find anything that actually works.

I'd love some help with this please!

---

If you're interested in the root of the problem - I have a data set which is built something like this:

```
ds={<|"date" -> "01/06", "a" -> 140., "b" -> 868., "c" -> 450., 
"d" -> 593., "e" -> 233., "f" -> 457.,
"g" -> 105.|>,

<|"date" -> "02/06", "a" -> 139., "b" -> 836., 
"c" -> 477., "d" -> 528., "e" -> 268., "f" -> 472., 
"g" -> 119.|>,

<|"date" -> "03/06", "a" -> 117., "b" -> 820., 
"c" -> 409., "d" -> 563., "e" -> 298., "f" -> 461.,
"g" -> 116.|>}
```

I'm trying to make a DateListPlot with all of the columns as lines, and "date" as the time series.
The easiest way to make a DateListPlot seems to be to transpose each column with the date column:

```
DateListPlot[Transpose[{Normal[ds[All, "date"]] , Normal[ds[All, "a"]]}]]
```

But I can't figure out how to do this for each column and then put all the columns into the DateListPlot as separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateListPlot[Transpose[{DateList[{#,
         {"Month", "YearShort"}}] & /@
      Map[Key["date"], ds], #}] & /@
  (Map[Key[#], ds] & /@
    {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"})]
```

or

```
DateListPlot[Transpose[{DateList[{#,
         {"Month", "YearShort"}}] & /@
      Map[Key["date"], ds], #}] & /@
  Transpose@Values@ds[[All,
      {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}]]]
```